# Laravel with html2canvas not saving the picture

Tags: laravel, html2canvas

I'm trying to use html2canvas and laravel. But when I click the `Save Report` button, the picture is not saving. I'm also not getting any error. Please see my code below.

`index.blade.php`

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
       <div class="content">
           <div class="title">Laravel 5</div>
           <p class="paragraph">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, veritatis dolores dicta at atque nobis maxime ea explicabo facilis molestiae voluptatibus nam nesciunt necessitatibus placeat ducimus magni nihil pariatur eligendi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga adipisci magnam in. Earum, nihil, expedita, blanditiis, iste ipsam amet obcaecati culpa ad quod itaque esse facere veritatis ratione ipsum quis.
           </p>
           <p class="paragraph">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, veritatis dolores dicta at atque nobis maxime ea explicabo facilis molestiae voluptatibus nam nesciunt necessitatibus placeat ducimus magni nihil pariatur eligendi.
            </p>
       </div>

        <button id="saveReport">Save Report</button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

`app.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var element = $('.content');

    $('#saveReport').on('click', function(){
        html2canvas(element, {
            background: '#ffffff',
            onrendered: function(canvas){
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/save-dashboard-report',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    data: {
                        base64data: imgData
                    }
                });
                alert('Success!');
                console.log(imgData);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

`controller`

```
public function save(){

    $data = $_REQUEST['base64data'];
    $image = explode('base64', $data);
    file_put_contents('1.jpg', base64_decode($image[1]));

}
```

`routes`

`Route::post('save-dashboard-report', 'DashboardReportController@save');`

Comment: First thing to check is. See your browser console. Find if there's any javascript error. After that, try to `dd($image);` in your controller to make sure the data is submitted.

Comment: where are you saving in your controller code ? also what datatype you are using for database.

Comment: @DharmaSaputra I'm not getting any error in console. `dd` only returns something like this `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAM`

Comment: @H45H This `file_put_contents('1.jpg', base64_decode($image[1]));` . I'm not saving it in the database; I'm saving it in folders or in the public directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
 public function save(){
       // decode your image first.
       $imagedata = base64_decode($_REQUEST['base64data']);
       // make random name
       $filename = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
       //path where you want to upload image
       $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads/'.$filename.'.png';
       file_put_contents($file,$imagedata); <-- Please follow this.
    }
```

Comment: Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware this is an old question, but I got here looking for the simplest example code for `html2canvas`, so let's make it work.

First things first: you're missing [CSRF protection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf). Somewhere in your `index.blade.php` just add

```
@csrf
```

Then, in your `app.js` send this token with the AJAX call data

```
data: {
    base64data: imgData,
    _token: $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content"),
}
```

After those two changes, we got a new error caused by the `file_put_contents()` function, which tries to write into the current folder. Simply, put the full path to a writable destination file. I did

```
file_put_contents(public_path('1.jpg'), base64_decode($image[1]));
```

*Et voilà*. It worked for me.